# Easier way to write to database using PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am new to PHPExcel, first time I've used it. I have written this piece of code, but I know that there is a better, faster way. At the moment, when I read the sample spreadsheet (6000 rows, same as the actual spreadsheet) it takes around 2 minutes on localhost.

So, in addition to making the code faster and more streamlined, is there a way to show the actual progress?

I have read through the documentation, but still struggle with this.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```php
/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../local_code/classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */ 
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter 
{ 
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') { 
        //  read columns A, C, G, H from row 2
        if ($row >= 2) { 
            if (in_array($column,array("A","C","G","H"))) { 
                return true; 
            } 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
} 

$inputFileName = 'newsheet.xlsx'; // change to uploaded file
$sheetname = 'FULL COMBINED';

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
$objReader->setReadFilter(new MyReadFilter()); 

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,false,false,true);
foreach($sheetData as $row => $columns) {
    if($row != 1) {
        $value = '';
        foreach($columns as $cell => $val) {
            if($cell == 'A') {
                $val = trim($val);
            }
            if($cell == 'C') {
                if(substr($val,0,1) != 'B') {
                    $val = trim($val);
                    $temp = substr($val,1);
                    if(is_numeric($temp))
                        $val = (int) $temp;
                }
            }
            if($cell == 'G') {
                $val = ($val * 86400) - 2209075200 - 86400;
            }
            if($cell == 'H') {
                $val == floatval($val);
            }
            if($val != "")
                $value[] = $val;
        }
        $values = "('" . implode("','",$value) . "')";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO projects_timesheet (employee_code,cost_code,date,hours) VALUES " . $values)or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

### Question 1

Is there a faster way of doing what I'm doing now? I know about chunking, but it seems I'm doing it wrong as it doesn't work.

### Question 2

Is there a way that I can show the user at what row the script currently is?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do with the cells in column G? It looks like date manipulation: why not use PHPExcel's built-in date handling functions?

Comment: Hi @MarkBaker, was expecting your reply. That's the thing, I don't know how. I had a read through the documentation, but still don't understand how to manipulate the date I get from the array to be a unix timestamp using the built-in function.

Comment: if($cell == 'G') {
                $val = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($val);
            } will return a PHP/Unix timestamp; or if($cell == 'G') {
                $val = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($val);
            } will return a PHP DateTime object

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work the first time, as I used it from the other question asked on SO regarding the date.

Comment: Mark, any suggestion on question 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have about 6k SQL inserts, try to insert all data by one SQL query.

Comment: Done that. Dropped the processing time to around 15 seconds. Yay me! :D